# Efficiently check if two numbers are co-primes (relatively primes)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, primes

What is the most efficient ("pythonic") way to test/check if two numbers are co-primes (relatively prime) in Python.

For the moment I have this code:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def coprime(a, b):
    return gcd(a, b) == 1

print(coprime(14,15)) #Should be true
print(coprime(14,28)) #Should be false
```

Can the code for checking/testing if two numbers are relatively prime be considered "Pythonic" or there is some better way?

Comment: Looks pretty good.

Comment: you could use `math.gcd` of course, which is a battery that's included and should be more performant.

Comment: Note: `math.gcd` is new in Python3.5, was `fractions.gcd` before.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only suggestion for improvement might be with your function `gcd`. Namely, you could use [`gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) that's defined in `math` (for Python `3.5`) for a speed boost.

Defining `coprime2` that uses the built-in version of `gcd`:

```
from math import gcd as bltin_gcd

def coprime2(a, b):
    return bltin_gcd(a, b) == 1
```

You almost cut down execution speed by half due to the fact that `math.gcd` is implemented in `C` ([see `math_gcd` in `mathmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L688)):

```
%timeit coprime(14, 15)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 907 ns per loop

%timeit coprime2(14, 15)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 486 ns per loop
```

For Python `<= 3.4` you could use `fractions.gcd` but, as noted in a comment by @user2357112, it is not implemented in `C`. Actually, *there's really no incentive to actually use it, [its implementation is exactly the same as yours.](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/fractions.py#l17)*

Comment: There isn't nearly as much of a benefit on pre-3.5, though, since `fractions.gcd` was written in Python instead of C.

Comment: Old question but math module functions in Python usually are no good for big numbers. It may crash. I would go for something like SymPy or PARI/GP

Comment: Would be great if you compare both of these:  `numpy.gcd()` vs `math.gdc()`.