# How to enhance the time complexity of finding if N is Coprime with the numbers from 2 till N using Python?

Tags: python, performance, math, time-complexity

I have wrote my code, it consists of 2 methods `coprime()` to check if 2 numbers are coprime or not and `count_coprime()` to count the numbers which are comprime with `n` and it works, yet it is too slow and I am looking for improvements:

1st:

```
def coprime(a, b):
    # Returns a boolean value
    # Returns true if a and b are in fact coprime
    if a == 1 or b == 1:
        return True
    else:
        count = 0
        if a < b:
            for i in range(2, a + 1):
                if a % i == 0:
                    if b % i == 0:
                        count += 1
        else:
            for i in range(2, b + 1):
                if b % i == 0:
                    if a % i == 0:
                        count += 1
        return count < 1
```

2nd:

```
def count_coprimes(n):
    count = 1
    for i in range(2, n):
        if coprime(i, n):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: [Efficiently check if two numbers are co-primes (relatively primes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39679114/1014587)

Comment: thanks for your comment, but what I want know is how `gcd()`  was implemented in such efficient way ? what is happening behind the scene ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether two numbers are coprime, you can use GCD ([Great Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)) algorithm. If `gcd(a,b)==1`, then values are coprime. It works in `O(max(log(a),log(b)))` time, so overall compexity is `O(logn)`.

There are some proofs for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980416/time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm).

Note that standard math module already contains `math.gcd()` function. Simple implementation of Euclid's algorithm:

```
def EuclideanGCD(x, y): 
    while y: 
        x, y = y, x % y 
    return x
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what I want know is how `gcd()`  was implemented in such efficient way? what is happening behind the scene ?

Comment: Knowing "gcd" term, you can easily find and read thousands descriptions and implementations. Added canonic Python implementation.